# HTML layout help with floating box

Tags: css

What CSS is needed to create such an HTML layout:

```
+--[li]---------------------------------------------+
|+--[div]-------------------------------------++---+|
|| A label with some text, truncate if necess…||BOX||
|+--------------------------------------------++---+|
|+--[div]------------------------------------------+|
|| Another label, truncate if necessary            ||
|+-------------------------------------------------+|
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

- the outer `<li>` is fixed-width, floating left with the other list items in the list
- the BOX should float to the right, above the upper `<div>`, it contains only two letters
- none of the text in the `<div>`s should wrap, overflow should be hidden
- the whole thing should work in IE7 quirks mode, preferably

Currently I have:

```
<li style="float: left; width: 175px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="float: right;">XX</div>
  <div>A label with some text, truncate if necessary</div>
  <div>Another label, truncate if necessary</div>
</li>
```

But I can't get BOX to hover over the first label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because right-floated div cannot float around nonwrappable text.

Try this

```
<li style="float: left; width: 175px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute; right: 0px; background-color: #FFFFFF;">XX</div>
  <div>A label with some text, truncate if necessary</div>
  <div>Another label, truncate if necessary</div>
</li>
```

if this what you want.

Comment: Absolute position brings the floated BOX out of its parent to the right border of the page.

Comment: It doesn't, because I added "position: relative;" into "li". I checked this in FF and IE8 - it works. Do you have different result?

Comment: Nice, thank you very much! :) (I've overlooked the li position)

Answer (score 1):

Is this the intended result?

[alt text http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/6603/boxf.jpg](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/6603/boxf.jpg)

```
<li style="float: left; width: 175px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="float: right; position: relative; background-color: red;">BOX</div>
  <div>A label with some text, truncate if necessary</div>
  <div>Another label, truncate if necessary</div>
</li>
```

Omitting the `position: relative`, you would get:

[alt text http://img360.imageshack.us/img360/7205/box2.jpg](http://img360.imageshack.us/img360/7205/box2.jpg)

Comment: In Standards Mode: yes, in Quirks Mode: no.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `float: left` the first label?

BTW, Firebug will help you a lot in debugging...

Comment: Changing nothing else `float: left;` does not make much of a difference I'm afraid.